# Extreme values of function with two variables $z=\frac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, extreme-value-analysis

I've been struggling with following problem:

> Determine extreme values of function
> $$
> z = \frac{ax+by+c}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}, 
> $$
> where $a^2+b^2+c^2 \neq0$.

Here is my approach:

As we know differential function can have extreme value only in stationary points, i.e. in point where derivative is zero. So let's calculate partial derivatives of given function. We have:
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} 
= \frac{a\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1} 
- \frac{ax+by+c}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}2x}{x^2+y^2+1} 
= \frac{ay^2+a-bxy-cx}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} 
= \frac{bx^2+b-axy-cy}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$

So now we need to solve system of equations
\begin{align}
&\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 0 \\[3pt] 
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0 
\end{cases} \\[5pt] 
\implies 
&\begin{cases} 
\hfil \dfrac{ay^2+a-bxy-cx}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = 0 \\[3pt]  
\hfil \dfrac{bx^2+b-axy-cy}{(x^2+y^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = 0 
\end{cases} \\[5pt]
\implies 
&\begin{cases} 
\hfil ay^2+a-bxy-cx = 0 \\[3pt] 
\hfil bx^2+b-axy-cy = 0 
\end{cases} 
\end{align}

Now I've been trying to solve this system of equations for long time but I just cannot do it :( It feels like there should be some clever way to solve this system, but I just don't see it.

Comment: Maple gives $x=a/c$ and $y=b/c$ as solution to your system.

Comment: Yeah. Mathematica gave me the same answer but I am looking for some clever way to solve this system. Of course there could be none.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we have that:
$$|ax+by+c| \leq |a| \cdot|x| + |b| \cdot |y| + |c| \cdot 1 \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}$$

Try doing some algebraic gymnastics with this :) This may still require some work but it should be easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

$$ay^2+a-bxy-cx = 0 \tag 1$$
$$bx^2+b-axy-cy = 0 \tag 2$$

From $(1)$,you have
$$x=\frac {a(y^2+1)}{by+c}$$ Plug $x$ in $(2)$ and simplify to obtain
$$\frac{(b-c y) \left(a^2 \left(y^2+1\right)+(b y+c)^2\right)}{(b y+c)^2}=0$$ So, there is one solution $y=\frac bc$ to which corresponds $x=\frac ac$.

What remains is to look at
$$a^2 \left(y^2+1\right)+(b y+c)^2= \left(a^2+b^2\right)y^2+2 b c y+\left(a^2+c^2\right)=0$$ which has no real root since
$$\Delta=-4a^2(a^2+b^2+c^2) ~~< ~0$$